# Creating an OAuth store

Tags: oauth

It seems like there are an abundance of Single Sign on solutions in the market (Okta, Bitium, Meldium) that allow a user to gather their identities from many different locations into one store.

I'm assuming the reason they can work with many hundreds of web applications, is they've created some kind of OAuth storage system that allows a user to tie {n} identities to their login.

What kind of system would they be using to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK they do not use oAuth, but they use SAML instead. SAML is a better solution for SSO, and this is what Okta, PingIdentity and others offer - an SSO platform.

Comment: Brilliant. Their are even some excellent SAML Open Source projects you can leverage for your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the solutions use SAML and not for all apps.  I know https://www.bitium.com, okta.com and onelogin.com all use SAML.  But for applications that don't have SAML implementations they'll use a browser extension to manage SSO.  Essentially they do a form filler function which injects passwords into the existing login form.  The browser extension calls the user's login information from the server database using a unique key and they inject the data into the login form using secure and encrypted data.

So if you want to integrate into hundreds of apps you'll need to consider open source options beyond SAML which is not yet available for all apps across the web.